# Is the `Integrate` function Riemann integration or Lebesgue integration?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have been under the assumption that `Integrate` performs Riemann integration. But when I try to integrate the Dirichlet function, it evaluates to $0$.

Dirichlet function is defined as follows:
$$
    f(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
    1 & x\in\mathbb{Q} \\
    0 & x\notin\mathbb{Q}
    \end{cases}
$$
Under Riemann integration, this function is not integrable; but under Lebesgue integration, this function evaluates to $0$.

So does it mean `Integrate` performs Lebesgue integration? Or is it neither and I am not even asking the correct question to begin with? Couldn't find anything in the documentation about this.

**EDIT**: My implementation of Dirichlet function is as follows:

```
f[x] := Piecewise[{{1, Element[x, Rationals]}, {0, True}}]
```

And the code for the integral is simply

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: How are you implementing the Dirichlet function in Mathematica?  I can't find a built-in, so you should include your code for it (or tell us what built-in function you *are* using).  Also, are you using `Integrate` or `NIntegrate` to do the integral?  Your code would be useful here as well.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I implemented it by doing a piecewise function with the condition `x \[Element] Rationals`; sorry, I'm not sure how to put in Mathematica code here yet.. And I used `Integrate` (not `NIntegrate`), but from $x=0$ to $x=1$

Comment: *Mathematica* is mostly a tool of applied mathematics. As such, it reflects the pragmatism of applied mathematicians. `Integrate` uses whatever theory of integration it can bring to bear to find a useful answer.

Comment: You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you, I have edited my code.

Comment: @JohnDoty That makes sense, thank you so much!